# Google Drive Authorized Code While Redirect URL WEBAPI

Tags: asp.net-web-api, google-drive-api

I am using Below Code to access Drive API, for that I am using WEBAPI not MVC Web Application.

```
var flow = new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow(new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow.Initializer
{
    ClientSecrets = new ClientSecrets
    {
        ClientId = "XXXXX",
        ClientSecret = "XXXXX"
    },
    Scopes = new[] { DriveService.Scope.Drive }
});

//  var result = new AuthorizationCodeWebApp(flow, "http://localhost:1344/api/AuthCallback/IndexAsync", "");
var result = new AuthorizationCodeWebApp(flow, "http://localhost:1344/api/GoogleImport/Listfile", "");
var resultData = result.AuthorizeAsync("user",CancellationToken.None).Result;
if (result1.Credential != null)
{
    var service123 = new DriveService(new BaseClientService.Initializer
    {
        HttpClientInitializer = resultData.Credential,
        ApplicationName = "ASP.NET MVC Sample",
    });

    var list = await service123.Files.List().ExecuteAsync();
}
else
{
    System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.Redirect(resultData.RedirectUri);
}
```

In webapi it's hard to Response.Redirect so how can I manage once authorized code result. Credential not populated?

Is there any other way to authorize code?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/dotnet/guide/aaa_oauth) to help you in your questions.

**OAuth 2.0**

> This document describes OAuth 2.0, when to use it, how to acquire
> client IDs, and how to use it with the Google API Client Library for
> .NET.

**OAuth 2.0 Protocol**

> OAuth 2.0 is the authorization protocol used by Google APIs. You
> should get familiar with the protocol by reading the following links:
>
> - [The OAuth 2.0 Authorization Protocol](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749)
> - [Using OAuth 2.0 to Access Google APIs](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2)

There is also a  provided sample code on how the OAuth 2.0 was implemented. Try to check it. You can do the same on your code.

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

using Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2;
using Google.Apis.Books.v1;
using Google.Apis.Books.v1.Data;
using Google.Apis.Services;
using Google.Apis.Util.Store;

namespace Books.ListMyLibrary
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Sample which demonstrates how to use the Books API.
    /// https://developers.google.com/books/docs/v1/getting_started
    /// <summary>
    internal class Program
    {
        [STAThread]
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Books API Sample: List MyLibrary");
            Console.WriteLine("================================");
            try
            {
                new Program().Run().Wait();
            }
            catch (AggregateException ex)
            {
                foreach (var e in ex.InnerExceptions)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("ERROR: " + e.Message);
                }
            }
            Console.WriteLine("Press any key to continue...");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }

        private async Task Run()
        {
            UserCredential credential;
            using (var stream = new FileStream("client_secrets.json", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
            {
                credential = await GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
                    GoogleClientSecrets.Load(stream).Secrets,
                    new[] { BooksService.Scope.Books },
                    "user", CancellationToken.None, new FileDataStore("Books.ListMyLibrary"));
            }

            // Create the service.
            var service = new BooksService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
                {
                    HttpClientInitializer = credential,
                    ApplicationName = "Books API Sample",
                });

            var bookshelves = await service.Mylibrary.Bookshelves.List().ExecuteAsync();
            ...
        }
    }
}
```